# Шестнадцатеричные числа в Си

Tags: c++, c, криптография, системы-счисления

Передо мной стоит задача реализовать алгоритм SEAL2.0.

Если вкратце, то на вход из файла подается 160 символьное слово, оно делится на 5 чисел шестнадцатеричной системы счисления по 32 символа. Далее происходят разные манипуляции с этими шестнадцатеричными числами: циклический сдвиг,  побитовое логическое умножение,  побитовое логическое сложение и т.д.

Я знаю, что Си поддерживает побитовые операции, шестнадцатеричные числа и может работать с ними. То есть можно сделать так:

```
char a,b,c;
a=0x2f;
b=0x1c;
c=a&b;// поразрядное "И"
```

Вопрос, можно ли как то использовать встроенные побитовые операции для больших шестнадцатеричных чисел в 32 знака? В каком формате тогда хранить такие большие числа, что бы с ними можно было работать?

Comment: что вам мешает применять битовые операции к любым другим целочисленным типам помимо char?

Comment: А какие целочисленные типы могут "вместить" 32 значное шестнадцатеричнное число? long int даже слишком мал...

Comment: Что такое "32 значное шестнадцатеричнное число"?

Comment: [gcc поддерживает __int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)

Comment: 32значное шестнадцатеричное число это число имеющее 32 разряда в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Например:
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

Comment: gcc поддерживает __int128, насколько я понимаю это класс и будет работать эта штука в С++ и по идее там не будут определены такие операции как циклический сдвиг или побитовое логическое умножение?

Comment: @kripiotkoo вы точно понимаете разницу между 16-ричной и двоичной системами счисления? То число, что вы привели - это по всей вероятности 32-разрядное **двоичное** число, которое может быть записано в обычную 4-байтовую переменную (обыкновенный long int обычно). В чем проблема использовать соответствующий тип данных?

Comment: @kripiotkoo, насчет циклического сдвига "из коробки" Вы правы (такой операции в Си нет). 

(Если не ошибаюсь, то циклический сдвиг числа v на N можно записать так
    
      ((v << N) | (v >> (sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT - N)))

)


А в остальном -- нет (хотя gcc -- это  Gnu Compiler Collection, но \_int128 это не класс, а один из целых типов, встроенных  в язык (в данном случае это GNU C Extension).

Comment: DreamChild, да я понимаю разницу, согласен, пример неудачный привел. Вот, например, такое число:
5021758d ce577cll fa5bd5dd 366dlb93
К сожалению в десятичной системе это 37 разрядов, что заметно больше long int.

Я думал есть какое-то расширение или какой-то хитрый способ использовать char, что бы можно было использовать встроенные побитовые операции. Но видимо такого метода нет:(

Придется запихивать все в char[32] и работать просто как со строками, написать функции для побитовых операций самому:(

Comment: @kripiotkoo мону ошибаться, но мне кажется, что это число может влезть в unsigned long long. Он, по-моему, есть в стандарте языка

Comment: @DreamChild, и long long (он же int64) и unsigned long long -- это 64 разряда (16 байт).

@kripiotkoo, у Вас какой компилятор (и ОС)?

Comment: если не хватает памяти на число я бы попробовал использовать шаблон bitset там можно произвольно задавать размер в битах и использовать побитовые операции. кстати это для чего он и был создан http://cppstudio.com/post/8501/

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет о потоковом криптоалгоритме [SEAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEAL_(cipher)), то ТС имеет ввиду 32-х битовые числа

Очевидно у ТС непонимание, того, что с точки зрения процессора 16-тиричное или  10-тичное число это всего лишь *представление* для удобства человека и не более того. Процессор в любом случае оперирует с битами.

Соответственно в зависимости от используемого компилятора/архитектуры надо выбрать способ хранения 32-х битовых чисел. Примерно так:

Windows(IA-32): `unsigned long int`

Windows (Intel 64): `unsigned long int`

Windows (IA-64): `unsigned long int`

Linux (IA-32): `unsigned long int`

Linux (Intel 64): `unsigned short int`

Linux (IA-64): `unsigned short int`

Mac OS X (IA-32): `unsigned long int`

Mac OS X (Intel 64): `unsigned short int`

Далее уже спокойно производить битовые манипуляции с нужными типами.

**P.S.** Никогда не реализуйте криптографические примитивы самостоятельно - никогда! Впрочем, ТС это видимо не указ :) - может такой у него курсач или дипломная работа?

Comment: > надо выбрать способ хранения 32-х битовых чисел. Примерно так:

а чем uint32\_t плох?

Comment: Да ничем не плох - бы сказал идеален. Я то давал совет в рамках чистого Kерниган-Риччи

Comment: Правда, в 

    Linux (Intel 64): unsigned short int 

это 2 байта (16 бит), а не 4 (для 32-х битовых чисел).

Для Mac OS X (Intel 64) проверить не могу, но интуитивно -- тоже 2 байта.

Comment: @avp: `short` не обязан быть 2 байта (16 бит -- минимальный размер, но может быть и больше). Хотя, я тоже не могу понять в какой используемой [модели данных](http://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0012/) `short` является 32 битным. Обычно приложения используют LP64 на 64-бит Юниксах и LLP64 на 64-битной Винде.

Comment: @jfs, так я же и не пишу, что short *всюду* 16 бит. Вот в Вашей таблице Cray -- 64 бита.

Какой размер в бэсм-6 или эльбрусе с их 48-разрядными словами и 15-разрядными адресными регистрами -- не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

не бейте сразу я плохо вопрос наверно понял но все же выложу свой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // эмуляция файла
    string file("dsfdskfjksdjfjsdfkldjsfjsdfjsdfdidfsdhfjsdjfdsfdshfdhfgggfdgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfrterghjghjhjhjghjhgjghjghfbvgrfhythgfhgfhgfhgfhtrhytrhgfhgfhhythjgngnjghjghjhgjdff");
    bitset<32> b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= file.size() - 5; i += 5){
        b1 = file[i];
        b2 = file[i + 1];
        b3 = file[i + 2];
        b4 = file[i + 3];
        b5 = file[i + 4];

        cout << "1: " << b1 << "\thex: " << hex << b1.to_ulong() << dec << "\t\tdec: " << dec << b1.to_ulong() << endl;
        cout << "2: " << b2 << "\thex: " << hex << b2.to_ulong() << dec << "\t\tdec: " << dec << b2.to_ulong() << endl;
        cout << "3: " << b3 << "\thex: " << hex << b3.to_ulong() << dec << "\t\tdec: " << dec << b3.to_ulong() << endl;
        cout << "4: " << b4 << "\thex: " << hex << b4.to_ulong() << dec << "\t\tdec: " << dec << b4.to_ulong() << endl;
        cout << "5: " << b5 << "\thex: " << hex << b5.to_ulong() << dec << "\t\tdec: " << dec << b5.to_ulong() << endl;
        cout << "----" << endl;

        result = b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5;
        cout << "example1 ----> 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 = " << result << endl;
        result = b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 & b5;
        cout << "example2 ----> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 = " << result << endl;

        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```